# Comparing two data frames according to several columns simultaneously in R

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames:

```
df1
Syllable Duration
Bis      0.18
Zeks     0.34
Ben      0.11

df2
Syllable Duration Pitch
Bis      0.18     78
Zeks     0.34     67
Bs       0.19     34
Ben      0.11     69
```

And I need to get a new data frame like this:

```
df3
Syllable Duration Pitch
Bis      0.18      78
Zeks     0.34      67
Ben      0.11      69
```

I've tried many things, but nothing gets me what I want. Any help would be of value to me.

This is one of the things I tried:

```
df1$Pitch <- df1$Pitch[match(df2$Syllable[df2$Duration],df1$Syllable[df1$Duration])]
```

Comment: Use this: `library(dplyr) ; inner_join(Df1,Df2, by = c('Syllable', 'Duration'))`

Comment: you can only use`match` on a single column. you want `merge`, like so `df1<-merge(df1, df2)`

Comment: just do `merge(Df1,Df2)` as stated by @Esther that will give 3 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are right. But if you have duplicates in your data, it can cause multiplications of rows in your outcome. Use this to get rid of duplicates:

```
df3 <- merge(df2, df1[!duplicated(df1$Syllable),], by="Syllable")
```