# Merging two data frames with certain conditions in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

```
df1
Syllable Duration Pitch
@         0.08    93
@         0.05    107
@         0.13    56
@         0.07    95
@         0.07    123

df2
Syllable Duration 
@        0.08 
@        0.05 
@        0.07
@        0.07
```

I want to merge them into another data frame:

```
df3
Syllable Duration Pitch
@        0.08     93
@        0.05     107
@        0.07     95
@        0.07     123
```

The problem is that I have repeated Syllable and Duration values. I've tried this code, but it gives me incorrect Pitch:

```
df3 <- merge(df2, df1[!duplicated(df1$Syllable),], by="Syllable")

df3
Syllable Duration Pitch
@        0.08     93
@        0.05     93
@        0.07     93
@        0.07     93
```

Comment: This is really somewhat difficult. How do you know which value pair is correct? Do you just want to keep the entries which are in df2 Syllable & Duration columns and filter out all values from df1 which are not in df2?

Comment: @rashid Yes, exactly. I want to filter out the rows that are not in df2. And the needed rows are going from top to bottom the way they are, so I guess it is somehow possible to do that.

Comment: Are you looking for an anti-join, i.e. exclude from `df1` those rows for which the combination of `Syllable` and `Duration` is not in `df2` ?

Comment: @jogo Yes, and I've tried a default anti-join as well. But it gave me repeated values, too.

Comment: imho it is a inner join of `df1` and `unique(df2)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691572/comparing-two-data-frames-according-to-several-columns-simultaneously-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose using the dplyr package. If you use it, you can select the columns which you want to join by. When you join, you should use an `semi_join` instead of an `inner_join`. The difference is that `inner_join` keeps all combinations and possibly duplicates rows ("If there are multiple matches between x and y, all combination of the matches are returned.")

`semi_join`on the other hand does: "A semi join differs from an inner join because an inner join will return one row of x for each matching row of y, where a semi join will never duplicate rows of x."

For your case, you can use `semi_join(df1, df2, by = c("Syllable", "Duration"))`to merge dataframes. The `by`vector defines the column names you want to join by.

This gives you what you wanted:

```
  Syllable Duration Pitch
1        @     0.08    93 
2        @     0.05   107
3        @     0.07    95
4        @     0.07   123
```

Answer (score 4):

With `data.table` you can do:

```
library("data.table")
df1 <- fread(
"Syllable Duration Pitch
@ 0.08 93
@ 0.05 107
@ 0.13 56
@ 0.07 95
@ 0.07 123")
df2 <- fread(
"Syllable Duration 
@ 0.08 
@ 0.05 
@ 0.07
@ 0.07")
merge(df1, unique(df2))
# > merge(df1, unique(df2))
#    Syllable Duration Pitch
# 1:        @     0.05   107
# 2:        @     0.07    95
# 3:        @     0.07   123
# 4:        @     0.08    93
```

or without sorting:

```
merge(df1, unique(df2), sort=FALSE)
# > merge(df1, unique(df2), sort=FALSE)
#    Syllable Duration Pitch
# 1:        @     0.08    93
# 2:        @     0.05   107
# 3:        @     0.07    95
# 4:        @     0.07   123
```

this last is the same as:

```
df1[unique(df2), on=c("Syllable", "Duration")]
# > df1[unique(df2), on=c("Syllable", "Duration")]
#    Syllable Duration Pitch
# 1:        @     0.08    93
# 2:        @     0.05   107
# 3:        @     0.07    95
# 4:        @     0.07   123
```

#### With base `R`:

```
df1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"Syllable Duration Pitch
@         0.08    93
@         0.05    107
@         0.13    56
@         0.07    95
@         0.07    123")

df2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"Syllable Duration 
@        0.08 
@        0.05 
@        0.07
@        0.07 ")
merge(df1, unique(df2))
merge(df1, unique(df2), sort=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#now keeps unique values for Syllable and the Pitch Values

df1 <- df1[order(df1$Syllable),]

df4<-merge(df2,df1)

df5<-df4[!duplicated(df4$Syllable),]
```

Comment: I can not get the desired result with your code. Did you test it?

Comment: Yes, I tested using the dataframe defined in this question. For the Pitch values I used (1,0,1,0,1). And it worked.

Comment: Can you put the used data in your answer (the question gave only a print of the dataframes) and can you please use the same Pitch values as in the question?

Comment: I just did with your same dataframes. I get for df5, 3 rows,with the values are join the 2 dataframes (syllable :0.5,0.7,and 0.8) with their corresponding pithc values. For me it's working. if you can give me further details we may be able to correct the code.